# SP 2010: Detect authentication mode

Tags: security

SharePoint 2010 with Claims-based Windows authentication returns 'Forms' from the Authentication.asmx Mode() call. Is this right? Asking this because actually this SharePoint will require Windows auth for accessing its web services.

I need this to say apriori which authentication mode (Windows vs Forms) should be used to access SharePoint web services. Any other ways to detect this not using Object Model, but via web services?